# If $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ is a Lie algebra and $V$ has a weight space decomposition, then $\mathfrak{h}$ is nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, over an algebraically closed field. Let $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ be a Lie subalgebra, and assume that $V$ has a weigth space decomposition $$V= \bigoplus_{\lambda \ \in \mathfrak{h}^\ast }V^\lambda(\mathfrak{h}) \\ \text{where }  \ V^\lambda(\mathfrak{h})=\{v \in V: \forall \ H \in \mathfrak{h}, \ \exists \ n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ with } (H-\lambda(H)I)^nv=0  \}, $$ Such that each $V^\lambda(\mathfrak{h})$ is $\mathfrak{h}-$invariant. Then $\mathfrak{h}$ is nilpotent. Here's where I got so far:

By Engel's theorem, it suffices to prove that $\forall \ H \in \mathfrak{h}, \ H$ is nilpotent. Suppose this is not the case, then choose $H \in \mathfrak{h}$ which is not nilpotent, then it has a non-zero eigenvector $v \in V$, with eigenvalue $\mu$. Choose $\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^\ast$ s.t. $v \in V^{\lambda}(\mathfrak{h}).$

Choose $k$ minimal with $(H-\lambda(H)I)^kv=0$, since $I$ and $H$ commute, we have:  $$0=(H-\lambda(H)I)^kv=\sum_{i=1}^k {n \choose i} \lambda(H)^{k-i}(-1)^iH^iv=\sum_{i=1}^k {n \choose i} \lambda(H)^{k-i}(-1)^i\mu^i v = (\mu-\lambda(H))^kv \\
\Rightarrow \lambda(H)=\mu \text{ and } k=1 \text{ by minimality of } k. $$ I think I should use the fact that the weight spaces are $\mathfrak{h}-$invariant to get a contradiction, but I'm stuck. Can someone help?

Comment: $H$ does not have to be nilpotent as an endomorphism of $V$. You can take any non-nilpotent endomorphism $H$ of $V$ and consider for $\mathfrak{h}$ the one-dimensional span of $H$ in $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$. The endomorphism $H$ admits a weight space decomposition because the ground field is algebraically closed, and this is then a weight space decompositon for $\mathfrak{h}$. But $\mathfrak{h}$ contains no nilpotent endomorphism except for the zero endomorphism.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Should I work with $ad_{\mathfrak{h}}(H)$ then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: I don't think that you need any deep theorem in order to prove the claim. The assumption tells you that choosing an appropriate basis of $V$, the elements of $\mathfrak h$ are all represented by block diagonal matrices with each block given by some multiple of the identity plus a strictly upper triangular matrix. But it is easy to see directly that the direct sum of multiples of the identity and strictly upper triangular matrizes is a nilpotent Lie algebra, which implies the claim.

Comment: But the lie algebra of upper triangular matrices is solvable, but not nilpotent.

Comment: It is not all upper triangular matrices but those for which all diagonal entries are the same, and these are nilpotent.

Comment: Got it, thanks!